# Statistical test to tell whether multiple samples come from the same distribution type

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference, multiple-comparisons

I have many samples $S_1,S_2,\dots ,S_n$. Each sample consists from different number of observations $O_1,O_2,\dots,O_n$. Now I want to conclude that all samples come from the same distribution type (let's say gamma). They should not come from the same distribution (shape and scale parameters in case of gamma may be different).

**Update:**
In other words, my hypothesis is that all samples come from gamma distribution. But I don't want to conclude anything about parameters. Each sample may come from gamma-distribution with it's own parameters.

**What should I do to be able to write something like this: "After XXX test we may conclude, that all samples are gamma-distributed. This fact will be used in further analysis.”**

Comment: You are envisioning the problem as a desire to get a dichotomous determination then making an all-or-nothing decision that disallows a gray zone.  It may be better to continuously quantify the gamma-ness of the distribution.  You might use the maximum absolute difference between best fit and empirical cumulative distribution function as such a metric, i.e., a Kolmogorov-Smirnov type of statistic.

Comment: I know how to use KS test for each given sample, not for all. I may average KS statistic and report it as a measure of gamma-ness. But still i have a question after which statistic i may deal with all samples like they come from gamma.

Comment: Please clarify your hypothesis, because it is ambiguous: are you asking whether (1) all samples are consistent with distributions from *some* (unspecified) two-parameter distribution family or (2) all samples are consistent with Gamma$(a,\lambda)$ distributions?

Comment: First. I am asking whether all samples comes from unspecified gamma distributions.